# flag whether actions are planned in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I want to flag for each day whether a patient has examinations scheduled on subsequent days. The starting point is

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

tribble(~ID, ~Date, ~Examination_Date,
        1, today(), today()+3,
        1, today()+1, today()+2,
        1, today()+2, NA,
        1, today()+3, NA,
        1, today()+4, today()+5,
        1, today()+5, NA)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID Date       Examination_Date
  <dbl> <date>     <date>          
1     1 2018-05-17 2018-05-20      
2     1 2018-05-18 2018-05-19      
3     1 2018-05-19 NA              
4     1 2018-05-20 NA              
5     1 2018-05-21 2018-05-22      
6     1 2018-05-22 NA
```

Which gives one row for each day and a Date in `Examination_Date` when a new examination was scheduled. The desired result is a column `examinations_scheduled` that flags whether there are still examinations due or not:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     ID Date       Examination_Date examinations_scheduled
  <dbl> <date>     <date>           <lgl>                 
1     1 2018-05-17 2018-05-20       TRUE                  
2     1 2018-05-18 2018-05-19       TRUE                  
3     1 2018-05-19 NA               TRUE                  
4     1 2018-05-20 NA               FALSE                 
5     1 2018-05-21 2018-05-22       TRUE                  
6     1 2018-05-22 NA               FALSE
```

How can I achieve that? I tried around with `tidyr::fill`, `spread` and siblings, but have problems tackling line 2 above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When asking a question in R, I would suggest using the [tag:r] tag.

Comment: Can an `Examination_Date` ever be scheduled for the same day?

Comment: Rows 3 and 6 seem to contradict each other in your results. Both have examination date = `NA`, both are equal to the examination date from the day above, but row 3 is TRUE and row 6 is FALSE. Why?

Comment: The expected result is correct. row 3 has date 20th still planned (from line 1) while row 6 has no open actions scheduled. useR: No, an event that is planned tomorrow is not open, but executed tomorrow and therefore not "planned" anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cummax` does most of what you need, though it doesn't work with dates or `NA`s the way you need, so you need to work around that...

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <-
  tribble(~ID, ~Date, ~Examination_Date,
          1, today(), today()+3,
          1, today()+1, today()+2,
          1, today()+2, NA,
          1, today()+3, NA,
          1, today()+4, today()+5,
          1, today()+5, NA)

df %>% 
  mutate(last_exam = as.integer(Examination_Date)) %>% 
  mutate(last_exam = if_else(is.na(last_exam), 0L, last_exam)) %>% 
  mutate(last_exam = cummax(last_exam)) %>% 
  mutate(last_exam = as_date(last_exam)) %>% 
  mutate(examinations_scheduled = last_exam > Date)

# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#      ID Date       Examination_Date last_exam  examinations_scheduled
#   <dbl> <date>     <date>           <date>     <lgl>                 
# 1     1 2018-05-18 2018-05-21       2018-05-21 TRUE                  
# 2     1 2018-05-19 2018-05-20       2018-05-21 TRUE                  
# 3     1 2018-05-20 NA               2018-05-21 TRUE                  
# 4     1 2018-05-21 NA               2018-05-21 FALSE                 
# 5     1 2018-05-22 2018-05-23       2018-05-23 TRUE                  
# 6     1 2018-05-23 NA               2018-05-23 FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you CJ, but the output in the question is as expected. The crux is line 2 (a new action is planned earlier than the last action was planned).

Comment: If you can adequately explain the difference between the pairs of rows 2&3 and 5&6, I will update my answer.

Comment: I just saw your last comment above. Now I understand what you want. It’s actually much easier now. I will update my answer when I get back to my computer.

Comment: I updated my answer so that it works they way you're expecting

Comment: Thank you so much! `cummax`, I learned something new now :) Thanks again!